# Grow vector by certain length and value combinations

Tags: r, vector, sequence

I have this vector:

```
a = c(4,5,6,81,82,83)
```

My desired result is the following:

```
b = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,78,79,80,81,82,83)
```

My logic is: There are two different sequences in `a` (this can be checked by using `length(which(diff(a)>1))+1`). Each one of them has to be extended from behind to reach the length of `1:end_of_first_seq` (`end_of_first_seq = a[which(diff(a)>1))[1]`). Thus, in this case the length of each sequence should be `6`. Each sequence must therefore grow three steps behind, so `4,5,6` becomes `1,2,3,4,5,6` and `81,82,83` becomes `78,79,80,81,82,83` while all being in the same vector.

Is there any fast way to do this? (this is a simple example, the number of sequences can be higher). It is worth mentioning all "previous" sequences are the same length (in this case, `3`) and they are separated by at least two values (a case like `6,7,8,9,10,11` cannot happen).  I know I can do this with loops but speed is a factor.

Comment: So every sequence has to be of length 6 because `length(1:end_of_first_sequence)` is `6`. What if there is a sequence which is more than length 6. So in this example if `a = c(4,5,6,81,82,83,84,85,86,87)`. Would 87 be removed ?

Comment: good question but, as I wrote, all "previous" sequences are of equal length. Also, two "prev" sequences are separated by at least 2 values. I will add that to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all sequences have same length:

```
vec <- c(4,5,6,81,82,83)  

LEN <- 3 # sequence length

want <- matrix(vec, ncol = LEN, byrow = TRUE)
want <- cbind(want - LEN, want)
want <- as.vector(t(want))
want
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 78 79 80 81 82 83
```

Answer (score 2):

We calculate length of each sequence and since all the sequence are of same length we can extract every `n`th value and create a sequence between two points in every sequence.

```
length_of_each_seq <- a[which.max(diff(a)>1)]
n <- 3

vals <- a[seq(n, length(a), by = n)]
c(mapply(`:`, vals - (length_of_each_seq - 1), vals))
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 78 79 80 81 82 83
```

where `vals` is the end of sequence

```
vals
#[1]  6 83
```

and `vals - (length_of_each_seq - 1)` is from where we need to start

```
vals - (length_of_each_seq - 1)
#[1]  1 78
```